# Match a float and multiply by 100

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I would like to extract a float from a coverage report and multiply it with 100 to report it as percentage.

I am able to match the float using `sed` or `grep` and then multiply it using `awk`, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant single tool solution, maybe with `perl` or `awk` only?

The line looks like this:

```
<coverage line-rate="0.34869999999999995" branch-rate="0.2777" >
```

My current solution:

```
sed -n 's/^<coverage line-rate="\([0-9\.]*\)".*$/\1/p' a.txt | awk '{print (100 * $1)}'
34.87
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to capture a number and process it, if matched, with Perl

```
perl -wnE'say 100 * $1 if /^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)"/' file
```

Another way to extract captures and process (multiply and print) them

```
perl -wnE'say 100 * $_ for /^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)"/' file
```

This uses the property of the match operator (`/.../`) to return the matches when in list context, provided by the `for` loop, in which we then process matches (only one in this case), multiply and print.  When there is no match the loop just won't have items to iterate over.

Both these process a file and merely print the result from lines that match, like in the question.  In both cases if a particular precision is wanted the `say` can be replaced by `printf ".2f\n", $x;` (two decimal places, etc).

---

I am not sure whether printing a number out of a one-liner is indeed the ultimate need or merely a simplified presentation for this purpose, but there are of course yet other ways.

One can also index into the list with matches in order to extract a captured pattern

```
my $num = ( /^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)/ )[0];
```

and then process after a check (whether there was a match), `$num *= 100 if defined $num;`

In case the input string need be changed, as is done in the question, perhaps for further work, to a particular precision

```
# Keep four decimal places
s/^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*).*/sprintf("%.4f", 100*$1)/e;
```

or if the precision doesn't matter and can be left to the interpreter

```
s/^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*).*/100*$1/e;
```

In both cases the `/e` modifier makes the replacement part be evaluated as code, so we can do some processing there. In the first case I use `sprintf` to format the replacement string while in the other case it's just multiplied.

---

There could be a potential complication here, about how many digits need be kept.  If it should be the same number as in the original then we may need to first detect how many that was

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# Number is shortened for demonstration
my $str = shift // q(<coverage line-rate="0.348691" branch-rate="0.2777" >);

sub process_num {
    my ($num, $frac) = @_;

    $num *= 100;
    my $frac_len = length($frac) - 2;  # keeps same digits

    return sprintf "%.${frac_len}f", $num;
}

$str =~ s/^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.([0-9]+)).*/process_num($1, $2)/e;

say $str;
```

Running this without arguments prints `34.8691` instead of the original line with `0.348691`

Thus assumes the number to have digit(s) for the fractional part, at least.

Comment: A bit cleaner than using `()[0]`: `perl -wnE'say 100 * $_ for /^<coverage line-rate="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)"/' file`

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I thought of that ... don't know which is clearer; I dislike that `()[0]` but `for` adds a whole loop -- conceptually more complex (code appears clearer to me as well).  Added it, thank you.

Comment: I consider that a false dichotomy. `()[0]` really requires a check to see if the pattern was found. It's also less adjustable (`/g`, for example)

Comment: @ikegami "_requires a check to see if the pattern was found_" -- for indexing?  That's a good point. And I guess it needs to construct a list that it can index into and there may be some overhead to that as well.

Comment: I meant one could end up with `100 * undef` using the `()[0]` approach without additional checks.

Comment: @ikegami Oh, that. Right, one-liner for this use (processing a file for lines of that format) needs fixing for that as many lines indeed _won't_ have that pattern. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/coverage line-rate="([^"]*)"/,arr){
  printf("%0.2f\n",arr[1] * 100)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `awk` program's `match` function, in `match` function using regex `coverage line-rate="([^"]*)"` which is matching string `coverage line-rate="` till next occurrence of `"` and saving capturing group's value into array arr. Then using `printf` to print value where using `%0.2f\n` to get value till 2 floating points only.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"` as field separator:

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2*100}' file
```

Output:

```
34.87
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk '/^<coverage /{
   print 100 * gensub(/.* line-rate="([0-9.]+)".*/, "\\1", "1")}' file

34.87
```